# use optim with a numeric vector under several constraints

Tags: r, math, optimization

In R, I want to create a function called `budget_optimal_allocation()` that uses two main parameters:

- `data`: a data frame
- `max_budget`: a numeric value

the objective of the function is to find the optimal level of spend for each channel in data that produces the best tot_ROI.

an example data frame is structured as such:

```
example_data <- data.frame(
  channel_name = c("Channel 1", "Channel 2", "Channel 3"),
  a = c(5000, 8000, 6000),
  b = c(0.001, 0.002, 0.0015),
  c = c(-1.05, -1.2, -0.95),  
  spend_min = c(100, 200, 150),
  spend_max = c(500, 800, 600)
)
```

`a`, `b` and `c` are (known) parameters of a response curve function that gets spend as input and generates a channel revenue, following the formula:

`revenue <- a / (1 + b * (spend) ^ c)`

also,

```
tot_revenue <- sum(revenue)
tot_spend <- sum(spend)
```

`tot_ROI` is calculated as tot_revenue / tot_spend

we want to optimise spend (for each channel name) so that tot_ROI is max. Therefore the function will optimise a VECTOR of spend, so all the channels at the same time, not one by one. This is very important, so the function has to be able to manage the optimisation of a vector, instead of iteratively looping channel by channel.

There will be some constraints in the optimisation:
each `channel_name` spend has to be within `spend_min` and `spend_max` defined in the input data frame, and `tot_spend` has to be equal to `max_budget` defined in `budget_optimal_allocation()`.

The following code is what I came up with so far, but

- I am not convinced is the right approach (is optim the right function to use?)
- I can't make `optimal_spend` = `max_budget`

```
budget_optimal_allocation <- function(data, max_budget) {
  # Extract channel names and parameters
  channel_names <- data$channel_name
  a <- data$a
  b <- data$b
  c <- data$c
  spend_min <- data$spend_min
  spend_max <- data$spend_max
  
  # Objective function to maximize total ROI
  objective_function <- function(spend, a, b, c) {
    # Calculate total revenue and total spend
    revenue <- a / (1 + b * (spend) ^ c)
    tot_revenue <- sum(revenue)
    tot_spend <- sum(spend)
    
    # Calculate total ROI
    tot_ROI <- tot_revenue / tot_spend
    
    # Minimize the negative total ROI (to maximize total ROI)
    return(-tot_ROI)
  }
  
  # Initial guess for spend values (equal allocation for each channel)
  initial_spend <- rep(max_budget / length(channel_names), length(channel_names))
  
  # Box constraints for spend
  lower_bounds <- rep(spend_min, length(channel_names))
  upper_bounds <- rep(spend_max, length(channel_names))
  
  # Optimize spend allocation to maximize total ROI with box constraints
  result <- optim(
    par = initial_spend,
    fn = objective_function,
    a = a,
    b = b,
    c = c,
    method = "L-BFGS-B",
    lower = lower_bounds,
    upper = upper_bounds,
    control = list(fnscale = -1)
  )
  
  # Extract optimal spend for each channel
  optimal_spend <- result$par
  
  # Combine channel names and optimal spend into a data frame
  optimal_allocation <- data.frame(
    channel_name = channel_names,
    optimal_spend = optimal_spend
  )
  
  return(optimal_allocation)
}

# Example data
example_data <- data.frame(
  channel_name = c("Channel 1", "Channel 2", "Channel 3"),
  a = c(5000, 8000, 6000),
  b = c(0.001, 0.002, 0.0015),
  c = c(-1.05, -1.2, -0.95),
  spend_min = c(100, 200, 150),
  spend_max = c(500, 800, 600)
)

# Max budget for optimization
max_budget <- 1000

# Run the optimization function
optimal_allocation <- budget_optimal_allocation(example_data, max_budget)

# Print the optimal allocation
print(optimal_allocation)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `optim` can solve your problem here since the problem is a ***constrained*** optimization problem with the constraint `max_budget`. A promising candidate would be `constrOptim`.

Two things you need to be aware of:

1. Since you have specified `fnscale=-1`, you don't need to return `-tot_ROI` In your `objective_function`; otherwise, it turns back to the minimization procedure.
2. You should have a explicit statement for the `sum(spend) <= max_budget`, which is critical in your constrained optimization problem.

## Code

Below is one implementation (I would like to move `objective_function` out of `budget_optimal_allocation`, since that would be easier to maintain the code if you need to change the objective function)

```
# Objective function to maximize total ROI
objective_function <- function(spend, a, b, c) {
    # Calculate total revenue and total spend
    revenue <- a / (1 + b * (spend)^c)
    tot_revenue <- sum(revenue)
    tot_spend <- sum(spend)

    # Calculate total ROI
    tot_revenue / tot_spend
}

budget_optimal_allocation <- function(data, max_budget) {
    # Extract channel names and parameters
    channel_names <- data$channel_name
    a <- data$a
    b <- data$b
    c <- data$c
    spend_min <- data$spend_min
    spend_max <- data$spend_max


    # Initial guess for spend values (equal allocation for each channel)
    init <- spend_min + sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)
    # Box constraints for spend
    k <- nrow(data)
    ui <- rbind(diag(k), -diag(k), -rep(1, k))
    ci <- c(spend_min, -spend_max, -max_budget)
    # Optimize spend allocation to maximize total ROI with box constraints
    result <- constrOptim(
        theta = init,
        f = objective_function,
        a = a,
        b = b,
        c = c,
        ui = ui,
        ci = ci,
        method = "Nelder-Mead",
        control = list(fnscale = -1)
    )

    # Combine channel names and optimal spend into a data frame
    return(list(
        optimal_allocation = data.frame(
            channel_name = channel_names,
            optimal_spend = result$par
        ),
        max_tot_ROI = result$value
    ))
}
```

## Output

With the same data as in your question

```
# Example data
example_data <- data.frame(
    channel_name = c("Channel 1", "Channel 2", "Channel 3"),
    a = c(5000, 8000, 6000),
    b = c(0.001, 0.002, 0.0015),
    c = c(-1.05, -1.2, -0.95),
    spend_min = c(100, 200, 150),
    spend_max = c(500, 800, 600)
)

# Max budget for optimization
max_budget <- 1000

# Run the optimization function
optimal_allocation <- budget_optimal_allocation(example_data, max_budget)
```

we will see

```
> optimal_allocation
$optimal_allocation
  channel_name optimal_spend
1    Channel 1           100
2    Channel 2           200
3    Channel 3           150

$max_tot_ROI
[1] 42.2219
```

---

## If you want to ***use up*** all the budget

You could have the following changes `init <- (spend_min + spend_max) / 2`, `ui <- rbind(diag(k), -diag(k), rep(1, k))` and `ci <- c(spend_min, -spend_max, max_budget)` 
So, the code is

```
budget_optimal_allocation <- function(data, max_budget) {
    # Extract channel names and parameters
    channel_names <- data$channel_name
    a <- data$a
    b <- data$b
    c <- data$c
    spend_min <- data$spend_min
    spend_max <- data$spend_max


    # Initial guess for spend values (equal allocation for each channel)
    eps <- sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)
    init <- (spend_min + spend_max) / 2
    # Box constraints for spend
    k <- nrow(data)
    ui <- rbind(diag(k), -diag(k), rep(1, k))
    ci <- c(spend_min, -spend_max, max_budget)
    # Optimize spend allocation to maximize total ROI with box constraints
    result <- constrOptim(
        theta = init,
        f = objective_function,
        a = a,
        b = b,
        c = c,
        ui = ui,
        ci = ci,
        method = "Nelder-Mead",
        control = list(fnscale = -1)
    )

    # Combine channel names and optimal spend into a data frame
    return(list(
        optimal_allocation = data.frame(
            channel_name = channel_names,
            optimal_spend = result$par
        ),
        max_tot_ROI = result$value
    ))
}
```

and you will see the output

```
> optimal_allocation
$optimal_allocation
  channel_name optimal_spend
1    Channel 1      252.1112
2    Channel 2      427.5322
3    Channel 3      320.3566

$max_tot_ROI
[1] 18.99994
```

and verify if all budget is used up

```
> sum(optimal_allocation$optimal_allocation$optimal_spend)
[1] 1000
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, ThomasIsCoding! It was very helpful to have some explanation about the function and the parameters. The only problem that I have from your code (and you can see it from the output you posted) is that ```sum(optimal_spend)``` < ```max_budget```... so we are not currently using all the budget - you mentioned to have an explicit statement, but at what point of the script do you place it?

Comment: @GNicoletti See the lines of `ui` and `ci`

Comment: yes, I noticed that you mentioned max_budget there, but the output of optimal_spend is 100 + 200 + 150 which is lower than the max_budget of 1000. Apologies if it is a very stupid question / observation, I am quite new with optimisation functions

Comment: @GNicoletti `max_budget` is the upper limit to distribute `spend`. You don't have to use it up, but you can never exceed your budget.

Comment: yeah, but as a constraint I want to use it all - I know that it may be more efficient to stop early, but I want to allocate all of it

Comment: @GNicoletti See the update

Comment: hmmm - weird.. in the example provided, the code works perfectly fine. When I move to a more business related data set, I get two possible outcomes:
a) at channel spend the optimisation seems fine (within spend min and max), but total budget constraint ignored (tot_spend > max_budget)
b) I get this error when I play with the max_budget:
Error in constrOptim(theta = init, f = objective_function, a = a, b = b,  : 
  initial value is not in the interior of the feasible region

which clearly seems related to init, so I tried ```init<-(sp_min+sp_max)/10``` but still get error - any advice?

Comment: @GNicoletti You should carefully choose the starting point `init` and ensure that `init` meets the requirements from the constraints; otherwise it would be recogonized as invalid starting point.

Comment: Yeah, this morning I went through it and there are a couple of points that I patched - all solved now. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem can be done with `optim` but you will have to do some algebra because `optim` was more geared to unconstrained optimization. It can handle boundaries relatively using methods `L-BFGS-B` and `Brent`, but no other constraints more complicated than that.

You can turn simple constrained optimization problems into unconstrained ones by using the Lagrange multipliers. In essence define a function that is identical to your original one, plus the constrains time a constant.

```
L = function(a,b,c,lambda) {objective_function(a,b,c)-lambda*(max_budget-sum(a,b,c))}
```

And maximize L.

I'm a little rusty in lagrange multipliers but this should penalize the objective every time you go above budget. The higher is the lambda the less lenient you are with going over budget.

Comment: Thanks for replying, JMenezes. the initial idea was this, indeed - but all the tests I have tried did not work as expected (mostly because I was trying to run a loop around the optimisation engine, which is clearly the wrong way)... I'll have a go at your solution